# seaborn colorbar same color for equal absolute values

Tags: seaborn, heatmap

I'm plotting a clustermap for correlation data. in my data, it doesn't matter if the value is positive or negative, just how much it's far away from 0 (stronger correlation). so, I want values with equal absolute values (0.5 & -0.5 for example) to have the same color in my heatmap, and the value 0 will be the center.
From what I have seen, there is no cbar appropriate. How can I do it?

Comment: The easiest way would be to pass the absolute value of your data (or dataframe).

Comment: correct, but than I will miss the cluters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom colormap with the dark color at the ends, and white at the center.  Using `vmin=-1, vmax=1` makes sure `0` will be white.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10, 4)
corr = np.corrcoef(data)

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['blue', 'white', 'blue'])
sns.clustermap(corr, cmap=cmap, vmin=-1, vmax=1, fmt='.2f', annot=True)
```

[image: sns.clustermap colored via absolute value]

Alternatively, you could choose one of matplotlib's 
 to differentiate between positive and negative values and still have a light color at `0`:

```py
sns.clustermap(corr, cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=-1, vmax=1, fmt='.2f', annot=True)
```

[image: sns.clustermap using diverging colors]